# jacoco-maven-plugin causes site plugin to fail in multimodule project

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

Last time I've decided to replace **Cobertura** plugin with **JaCoCo** plugin in my Java projects Maven builds.

One of them is a multimodule project with inter-module dependencies:

```
*-- pl.chilldev.commons
    |-- commons-concurrent
    |-- commons-daemon
    `-- commons-exception
```

The thing is that `commons-daemon` depends on `commons-exception`.

I have `jacoco-maven-plugin` configured following way:

```xml
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.1.201405082137</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-report</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Everything works, tests are run, but `site` target fails with:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3:site (default-site) on project commons: failed to get report for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin: Failed to execute goal on project commons-daemon: Could not resolve dependencies for project pl.chilldev.commons:commons-daemon:jar:0.0.3-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact pl.chilldev.commons:commons-exception:jar:0.0.3-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

Without `jacoco-maven-plugin` everything works fine even for `site` target.

Comment: are you running a `mvn install` or `mvn package`

Comment: I wrote clearly, that it applies to target `site`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to make it working. Problem is, that by default `prepare-agent` goal binds to `initialize` phase which means everything will be executing using JaCoCo java agent which probably is unable to resolve classpath before they are computed by Maven (I just assume that, I don't know internals).

Adding:

```xml
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.1.201405082137</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Fixed it.

BTW - It's also not needed to add `report` goal into executions list, I think it's more correct to add it into reporting plugins.